# How to create a (key, value1, value2) file in java similar to (key, value) property file

Tags: java

Can you please suggest how to create (key, value1, value2) file in java similar to (key, value) property file. Do any open source project uses such type of file.

Comment: so you want to use the `java.util.Properties`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) has the [PropertiesConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html) class that supports multiple values for a single key.

See [here](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Lists_and_arrays) for an example.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a delimiter:

```
props.put(key, value1 + DELIMITER + value2);
```

you can also use a key-suffix:

```
props.put(key + "1", value1);
props.put(key + "2", value2);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also use the apache commons collection package it has a handy MultiValue map implementation.
See the [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of `multi-valued` property files. The `Properties` class extends from Hashtable. You can create a new class that makes use of `Hashtable<String, String[]>`

Take the source code of [java/utils/Properties.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Properties.java.html) and modify accordingly.

Here is how your property file should look like:

```
key1 = value
key2 = value_1
key2 = value_2
key3 = my_value_3
```

Comment: nice idea, but how it will be represented in the `.properties` file?

Comment: That will depend on how you modify java/utils/Properties.java. One suggestion is to use your own idea ;) (note: I am not the author of the answer)

Comment: added a sample. as indicated by @peter you can use your own idea; multi-line looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could extends Map interface, something like :

```
public class Multimap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V[]> {

 @Override
 public V[] put(K key, V...value) {
  return super.put(key, value);
 }

}
```

Then

```
Multimap<String,String> mapStr = new Multimap<String, String>(); 
mapStr.put("key1", "value1", "value2");
System.out.println("Strings: key1 = " + Arrays.toString( mapStr.get("key1") ) );


Multimap<String,Integer> mapInt = new Multimap<String, Integer>(); 
mapInt.put("key1", 1, 2);
System.out.println("Integers: key1 = " + Arrays.toString( mapInt.get("key1") ) );
```

Would yield

```
Strings: key1 = [value1, value2]
Integers: key1 = [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this.

```
prop1 = one
prop2 =two
#prop12 is a multivalued property.values are the combination of prop1 and prop2
prop12= prop1,prop2
```

Assuming that the property file has entries like this.

```
public class MVProperties extends Properties{

 public List<String> getMultiValuedProperty(String key){
    List<String> values = null;
    String[] references = getProperty(key,"").split(",");
    if(references.length == 0){
        return values;
    }
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String ref:references){
        values.add(getProperty(ref));
    }
    return values;
   }
}
```

Comment: Here how user will pass the key #chedine ??

Answer (score 0):

Use (key,value[]) instead

Comment: If I correctly assumed he wants to use `java.util.Properties` in order to save the structure to a properties file, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it has already been suggested - if however you were looking for a way to modify a class that implements the Map interface to accept 2 values instead of just 1 then be careful.  The Map interface has lots of methods that may behave in unexpected ways if you try this - it can be done its just a lot more work than it may be worth :)

Comment: This is not true.. see my answer :)